# geo_point not mapping correctly in nested model

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoosastic

I am using moongosastic to map mongodb to elastic search.

I have a nested model:

```
var officeSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    location: {
        geo_point: {
            type: String,
            es_type: 'geo_point',
            es_lat_lon: true
        },
        lat: {type: Number},
        lon: {type: Number}
    }
});

var businessSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.ObjectId,
    name: {type:String, es_indexed:true}
    office: {type:[officeSchema], es_indexed:true}
});
```

but the office mapping geo_point result is a string:

```
"office": {
      "properties": {
          "location": {
             "properties": {
                 "geo_point": {
                      "type": "string"
                  }
              }
          },
```

Should I do createMapping? How should createMapping looks like?

Answer (score 0):

If you still have a problem, you should modify mapping of that type of index :

http://localhost:9200/log-2015/_mapping/type/ with POST

```
  {
     "type": {
     "properties": {
     "location": {
           "type" : "geo_point"
    }
```

And if you will find a problem of conflict in kibana just create an other index

}